# How to call a controller action outside magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, controllers

We can create php scripts which runs outside magento. And also use magento functionalities by using the following code snippet in it.

```
define('ROOT', '');
    $mage_php_url = ROOT.'app/Mage.php';

    if (!empty($mage_php_url) && file_exists($mage_php_url) && !is_dir($mage_php_url))
    {
        // Include Magento's Mage.php file.
        require_once ( $mage_php_url );
        umask(0);
        Mage::app();
    }
```

In these type of scripts we can directly call models, blocks, helpers etc. But how can we call to a controller action in here ? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: why would you need this and not do a request to that controller/action directly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Magento isn't really designed to do this, which means you **can** use controller objects as you would any other object, but there will be complications.  Since  these methods are meant to be called from an HTTP context, they'll very often do things with the request and response objects, or rely on some bit of session state that just doesn't exist when you're running things from the command line.

That said, the following will work

```
// require you file        
if(!class_exists('Mage_Customer_AccountController')) //in case the class already exists
{
    require_once('Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php');        
}

// instantiate your controller, using the `Mage:app()` object to grab the required request and response
$controller         = new Mage_Customer_AccountController(
                            Mage::app()->getRequest(),
                            Mage::app()->getResponse()
                        );        

// grab request and response object to manipulate as needed 
// (i.e. controller action expects post variables, etc.)

$request            = $controller->getRequest();
$response           = $controller->getResponse();

//manipulate things as per above

//call the action
$controller->someAction();
```

Comment: How to pass Param in non parameterised action of core controller with$controller->someAction(); as in my case i need to remove wishlist item from index controller's removeAction()

Comment: Pls let me know how to use in magento 2? I'm try using with include controller class into __construct function but it not pass `must be an instance`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

`file_get_contents('http://url.com/[...]/controller/action/');`

Done! :)

Or you can override the request (so it seem like the request is to that action) and then just call `Mage::run()`.

On a more serious note, depends a lot on what you are actually doing in that action. Do you need Magento instantiated, do you need the entire request flow and so on.

If you don't need the request flow and so on, you can do:

```
Mage::app();
require_once 'path/to/controller.php';
$my_controller = new YourController;
$my_controller->doSomething();
```

If you need more the you can start digging by looking at `Mage::run()` function. 
Another good starting point is `api.php`, where you can see how to instantiate a lightweight version of Magento. Then just follow the request flow.

Looking at Alan's comment:
If your controller is an instance of `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` (and your Magento controllers should be), you need to send a request object and a response object to the contructor:

```
 public function __construct(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract $response, array $invokeArgs = array())
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_response= $response;

        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->setAction($this);

        $this->_construct();
    }
```

Comment: Controller objects require a request and response object in their constructor.

Comment: two not recommended ways at once :-(
requesting data by calling own uri and doing this with fopen & co