# How do I call a controller class from a template?

Tags: magento-1, controllers

I have a template, which is included in the transactional email using this code:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='myname_mymodule/pdffile.phtml' order=$order}}
```

and in the  pdffile.phtml file i have:

```
$pdf  =  new Namespace_Module_PdfController();
```

I get a fatal error with class not found. 
Can someone help with this ? thx

Comment: as marius said you can't. and if you want to instantiate controller you need to call require_once before instantiate controller as controller is not auto loaded by default.

Comment: @MineshPatel. You can actually instantiate controllers, but it's a really bad idea. Alan Storm explains it how in here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8751/146

Comment: yes @Marius. Business logic should be in model and not in controller files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should never instantiate controllers inside template.
Actually you should never instantiate controllers manually.
If you have a custom behavior, put it inside a model or a template and call it inside the controller and inside the template.