# Calling another controller and getting a response

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

This is a question about a solution provided on previous post...

[How to call a controller action outside magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8720/how-to-call-a-controller-action-outside-magento/8751#8751)

my question is how to get the response from the function being called on the controller. Also how to post to the controller function.

// grab request and response object to manipulate as needed 
// (i.e. controller action expects post variables, etc.)

$request = $controller->getRequest();
$response = $controller->getResponse();

Answer (score 0):

To get param:

$request->getParam('order_id');

Using Response:

$response->setRedirct(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));